# Composition with a continuous map preserves $L^p$ convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Assume we have $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p(U)$, where $U$ is a bounded set of an Euclidean space. Is it true that for any continuous $F$, $F(f_n) \rightarrow F(f)$ in $L^p(U)$ as well? It is clear when $F$ is Lipschitz.

Probably this is simple, but I could not find a counterexample yet.

Comment: In general $F(f)$ might not even be in $L^p$.

Comment: You are right, I want to assume that $F$ is bounded as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$f_n = n\chi_{\left[0,\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\right]}$$
and
$$F(x) = x^{\frac{p+1}{p}}.$$
Then $\|f_n\|_{L^p} = n^{-\frac{1}{p}}\rightarrow 0$, but $\|F(f_n)\|_{L^p} = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I like this example!

Comment: But is it true that we have weak convergence in $L^p$?

Comment: @user45824 That's not guaranteed either. You can easily modify my example to get $\{f_n\}$ such that $\|f_n\|$ still goes to $0$, but $\|F(f_n)\|$ actually diverges to $\infty$ (which is impossible for weak convergence)